# unable to load csv from GCS bucket to BigQuery table accurately

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am trying to load the `airbnb_nyc` data set from GCS bucket to `BigqueryTable`. [Link](https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data) to the dataset.

I am using the following Code:

```
def parse_file(element):
for line in csv.reader([element],delimiter=','):
    return line

class DataIngestion2:
def parse_method2(self, values):
    row1 = dict(
        zip(('id', 'name', 'host_id', 'host_name', 'neighbourhood_group', 'neighbourhood', 'latitude', 'longitude',
             'room_type', 'price', 'minimum_nights', 'number_of_reviews', 'last_review', 'reviews_per_month',
             'calculated_host_listings_count', 'availability_365'),
            values))
    return row1

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
  lines=  p | 'Read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input,skip_header_lines=1)\
           | 'parse' >>  beam.Map(parse_file)

pipeline2 = lines | 'Format to Dict _ original CSV' >> beam.Map(lambda x: data_ingestion2.parse_method2(x))


  pipeline2 | 'Load2' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table_spec, schema=table_schema,
                                              write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                                              create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
                                              )
```

`

But my output on BigQuery Table is wrong.

I am only getting values for the first two columns and the rest of the 14 columns are showing NULL. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Can Someone Help me find the error in my logic. I basically want to know how to transfer a csv from GCS bucket to `BigQuery` through `DataFlow` pipeline.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ReadFromText method and then create your own transform by extending beam.DoFn. Attached the code below for reference.

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.32.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromText

Note that you can use gs:// for GCS in file_pattern.

More details about Pardo and DoFn

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.textio import ReadAllFromText,ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import WriteToBigQuery
from apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio import GcsIO
import csv

COLUMN_NAMES = ['id','name','host_id','host_name','neighbourhood_group','neighbourhood','latitude','longitude','room_type','price','minimum_nights','number_of_reviews','last_review','reviews_per_month','calculated_host_listings_count','availability_365']

def files(path='gs:/some/path'):
    return list(GcsIO(storage_client='<ur storage client>').list_prefix(path=path).keys())

def  transform_csv(element):
    rows = []
    with open(element,newline='\r\n') as f:
        itr = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',',quotechar= '"')
        skip_head = next(itr)
        for row in itr:
            rows.append(row)
        return rows

def to_dict(element):
    rows = []
    for item in element:
        row_dict = {}
        zipped = zip(COLUMN_NAMES,item)
        for key,val in zipped:
            row_dict[key] =val
        rows.append(row_dict)
    yield rows

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    read =(
        p
        |'read-file'>> beam.Create(files())
        |'transform-dict'>>beam.Map(transform_csv)
        |'list-to-dict'>>beam.FlatMap(to_dict )
        |'print'>>beam.Map(print)
        #|'write-to-bq'>>WriteToBigQuery(schema=COLUMN_NAMES,table='ur table',project='',dataset='')
    )
```

**EDITED1** The ReadFromText supports \r\n as newline char.But,this fails to consider the condition where column data itself has \r\n. Updating the code below.

*EDITED 2* GcsIo error fixed.

Note - I have used GCSIO for getting the list of files.
Details [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.24.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio.html)

Please Up-vote and mark as answer if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I noticed that When I use ReadFromText method, some of the rows are breaking into two lines which is actually causing them to have blanks. The other rows that fit in a single line are coming out fine when I upload in BIgquery. By any chance do you know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Yes, there could be a case when the data has newline chars (\r\n or \n) in it. For eg. if there is a column "comment" in csv which has multiline comments with new line characters then the reader sees it as a new row instead of considering it a column. You have to make sure that the columns have data in quotes ("").

Comment: They do have quotes. I still don't know how to handle them. Do you have any idea?

Comment: can yu attach the sample data?

Comment: I have provided link to the dataset in the question, it's on kaggle. The dataset has a description column with quotes where all the new line characters are occurring.

Comment: I have edited the answer I provided earlier. Due to limitations of ReadFromText, I have now used CSV and GCSIO modules. Please have a look. Please go thru the new code.

Comment: I am getting this error when I try that code.
WARNING:apache_beam.utils.retry:Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 4.035109665602334 seconds before retrying list_prefix because we caught exception: TypeError: list_prefix() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
 Traceback for above exception (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akhil_kv228/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 253, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: I am not very familiar with GCP. How do I create a storage client. I tried this with your code:               
 storage_client = storage.Client(), but it is throwing the following errors:          
    AttributeError: type object 'GcsIO' has no attribute 'client'

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest another approch for this use case. BiqQuery offers special feature for uploading from Google Could Storage (GCS) to Bigquery. You can load data in several formats and CSV is among them.

There is nice [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#python) on Google documentation explaining how to do it. You do not have to use Dataflow or apache_beam. Such process is available through BigQuery API itself.

This is working in many languages, but you do not have to use any language as such process can be done from console or via Cloud SDK using `bq` command. Everything can be found in mentioned tutorial.